# C# how do I make string from array of string?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Can you tell me an easy way to make a string from array of string?

I have:

```
String line = "how are you";
string[] split = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }); //{"how", "are", "you"}
```

How i can make back "String - How are you"? IT IS ONLY EXAMPLE, NOT REALITY :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
string.Join(" ", split);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and if i need make a this string = '"are you"' without 'split[0]'?

Comment: @coudrouf `string.Join(" ", split.Skip(1));`

Comment: Thank you, its possible skip index number X ?

Comment: Sure. `string.Join(" ", split.Where((s, x) => x != 1));`